# Why do special characters which have been encoded in ajax call show up as different special characters?

Tags: php, ajax, character-encoding

In one of the user inputs on my site, a user can input strings that are alphanumeric + special characters. After the user inputs the data, clicking a button calls an ajax function that looks basically like this:

```
    function ajaxEZ(id, x) {
    var ajaxRequest, param;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e1) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e2) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e3) {
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    };
    param = encodeURIComponent(x);
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "AJAX_file.php?param=" + param, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

The encodeURIComponent(x) is for specials such as &. Currently, I am testing a user input of **5i√2** ( as **`5i&radic;2`** ). The input is sent to a php file which compares the string to the "correct" answer which is present in one of the database tables.

The problem is that even if the encoded string is decoded, this particular string **5i√2** is stored in the appropriate table as:

```
5iâˆš2
```

I tried decoding the string in my php file:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$UserAnswer = $_GET['param'];
$UserAnswer1 = urldecode($UserAnswer);
$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "INSERT INTO myTable (answer) VALUES ('$UserAnswer1')");
```

However, the string is still stored in the database as:

```
5iâˆš2    (This is the same result whether or not the urldecode is present)
```

For the table *myTable*, the collation is: latin1_swedish_ci

I would like the string that is stored to be **`5i&radic;2`**

Note that as a side problem, the correct answer, stored as **`5i&radic;2`** does not compare as "equivalent" to the user input even if the user input is **`5i&radic;2`**

However, the strings do compare as equivalent if the correct answer is stored as **5i%E2%88%9A2** and the user input is also **5i%E2%88%9A2**

Can someone please shed some light on exactly what is going on? Why does the php-decoded string (urldecode($UserAnswer)) not get properly decoded and winds up being stored as 5iâˆš2   ? Note also my HTML charset is utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` parameters are already decoded, so you are decoding it twice. You should remove:

```
$UserAnswer1 = urldecode($UserAnswer);
```

Apart from that you probably receive a `√` character so if you want to encode that for html before you store it in the database, you should use [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead:

```
$UserAnswer1 = htmlentities($UserAnswer);
```

Although I would personally go for utf8 for everything.

You should also use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Whether the urldecode is present or not, the same unwanted character string is stored in the table myTable. I will edit my post to make this more clear to users...my bad.

Comment: Thank you...now the entry stores properly in myTable (stores now as 5i&radic;2). Perhaps for this same reason the strings do not compare as equivalent?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob What are you comparing? A html encoded string with special characters will definitely not match an unencoded string. You'd need `html_entity_decode()` to get the original characters back.

Comment: Great answer...the correct answer was present in myTable as 5i&radic;2 so I had to compare (after multiple different str_replace() steps): if ($CorrectAnswer == htmlentities($UserAnswer)) etc....works perfectly now